# JQuery how write particular selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I would like to select with JQuery this element (see html code from browser) and I'm running out of ideas. I need to select all three of them, selectable, selected and number=55.

```
<span class="selectable selected" number="55"></span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu you forgot the quotes and the OP says he needs all three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get all three you can do

`$('.selectable.selected[number="55"]')`

Comment: This  option does what I need, thanks. Tried it on JSfiddle, it's working. In my environment it doesn't work, I'll figure it out, thanks.

Comment: Console's clear.. i tried also to switch single and double quotes, the result didn't change.

Comment: is the html dynamically loaded and also how are you using the selector?

Comment: Found the mistake. Selector was fine, but was called by an event that never fired..   Thank u very much, all of  you.

Answer (score 0):

var span = $(".selectable.selected");

Comment: I need also the number attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select **ANY** of the 3 you need

```
$('.selectable, .selected, span[number="55"]')
```